# Is it still a good practice to log parameters and returns?

Tags: java, logging, spring

Just a context, I am currently making a base code for a Java Spring Boot Application.

I am currently setting up the logging of the application and I stumbled upong [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/10-tips-proper-application-logging.html) url and found it helpful. Although it is a little bit outdated.

**Questions**

1. In the url, `7) Log method arguments and return values`, is this still relevant today? Should I manually do it in my methods?
2. In an MVC application, should I do it in all layers? (Controllers, Services, and DAOs)?

Comment: That link is incorrect.

Comment: Fixed sorry. Never know that overrides your clipboard nowadays :D

Comment: Has that ever been relevant?

Comment: I'm sorry I just assumed it was. But if weren't in the first place then you could just say so.

Comment: 1. I do not think hard code in the method is good idea. This seems a job for a decorator. 2. Unit test should be the better way to find the problem in method arguments and return value and should cover everything. Logging in my opinion is not necessary to be done everywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think that article is implying that *every* method should should be logged that way, it's just saying *when* you're logging make sure you capture the context in which the log occurred.

For example, if you have a log which says only "User cannot be found", if you're actually trying to understand the scenario which lead to that log then you probably need to know the user ID at least. Typically function arguments have the most significant affect on the output of a function so that's the most important context to capture, but class or global variables might also be just as important depending on the situation.

In the case of a Spring web application, I definitely wouldn't be putting logging in every single function, but I would be logging where failures are likely. For example, if you make a call to an external service.

The article itself states:

> Of course, you must be reasonable but every method that: accesses
>   external system (including database), blocks, waits, etc. should be
>   considered.

Although, some of this logging might already be provided by your ORM or RDBMS so I wouldn't go adding logging to every single database call either.

The article also states:

> You should consider DEBUG or TRACE levels as best suited for these
>   types of logs.

Which typically aren't logged in production, so you might consider it an alternative to temporary print/echo statements during development. Again, only where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Are you ever going to use the information logged?

It could be possibly be useful for debugging but then you will probably use a debugger anyway.

I have worked on projects where practicality everything was logged, but there was a real business requirement -- they needed forensic proof if bad/fraudulent behavior by "trusted" associates was detected.

Answer (score 0):

From my option - logging parameters and return values must be present but turned off by default. E.g. by default nothing is logged or just needed things. But when somethings goes wrong you can easy enable logging via file config changing (log4j and logback support config updating with time interval).

What it give for you and what my goes wrong?

1. First of all this approach is very usefully for situations when you can not run you code locally. For example aws lambda which may needs some security setting and may communicate with some other aws resources. In that case you can easy enable logging and rerun lambda to see what happens.
2. Consider you production environment when bug can not be reproduced locally. In case when issue is hard to reproduce you can just enable extra logging for limited time (1 minutes or less for example) and see what happens in production. Small time period limit performace degradation for extra logging.
3. Often during developent you code and then think - "It does not work, I have to add logging more here". Possibility of logging methods and parameters leads to less coding.

Do not mix bussines logging logic and logging for debug

For example if you work with external system it is better to add logging directly like: `logger.info("Order created id={}", id)` then enable all logging for all layer to see order id in logs.